# Http request with jmx

Tags: json, hive, jmx, zabbix

Good afternoon!
I try to get data from apache hive in JSON by zabbix http-agent and it works. But I have unpleasant situation, JSON data have more than 180000 chars. This is a problem, because MYSQL field has just 65535 max chars (my performance, I no want to change it).
In this way JSON data in MYSQL field isn't valid (incomplete).

I found, as I think, a solution - it's http request with parameters.
For example:

```
http://localhost:port/jmx                      - full JSON data
?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeInfo - data which I need
http://localhost:port/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeInfo - full request
```

I made zabbix template and zabbix item.
Item has next options:

```
Type: http-agent
URL: http://{HOST.CONN}:10010/jmx?qry=metrics:name=api_runTasks
Type of information: text
```

I get incomplete JSON data in zabbix "latest data" with next url: http://localhost:port/jmx

I get empty JSON data with next url: http://{HOST.CONN}:10010/jmx?qry=metrics:name=api_runTasks

I was trying to tune zabbix agent with query field where *name field* is **qry** and *value field* is **metrics:name=api_runTasks** (I was trying many of combinations and was getting just two messages in zabbix history of latest data there are):

```
{"body":{ "beans" : [ ] }} or
{ } or
full incomplete JSON data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix item needs to have next options:

```
URL: http://{HOST.CONN}:10010/jmx
```

Query fields:

```
name: qry
value: metrics:name=api_compile
```

Hive 2.0 have by default two enabled ways to log metrics, there are JMX and JSON file /tmp/report.json